# I'm having trouble getting my texture paint to show up in render/material preview

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have this nice grainy white texture I've been using, and I want to draw some rust on it using texture paint. But the rust only shows up in solid mode view, and disappears when I switch to material preview or render view. Any clue on how to solve this issue?

Here's a video of the issue: https://youtu.be/6w2wEEKd0CU

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you save the painting status to disk? Does the update then show up in the different view modes?

Answer (score 0):

At the material preview the things get really brighter and the colors that you used are shades of white. I think your problem is because of this.